# Your app uses a defective version of the OpenSSL library, which can cause your app to crash. Update to a fixed version of OpenSSL

Tags: react-native, realm

Hii there I got this error on google play console when i am tried to. publish my app on google play store. i am using these dependencies

"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.4",
"realm": "^10.24.0",

the error-:
Defective versions:
OpenSSL 1.1.1g in lib/x86/librealm.so

please help  i am stuck here more then 4 days

please help me to get rid out of this

Comment: In reading [the project README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/realm) on the npm page, it leads to a [compatability matrix](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/HEAD/COMPATIBILITY.md). Note that your version of `react-native` is unsupported for your version of `realm`: You need `react-native` of version `0.71.4` or higher. Your version of react is fairly out of date too, and `realm` has version 11.8.0 out (though the `10.24.0` is only 5 months old).

Comment: @Rogue Right on! Note that Realm 10.24.0 is from March 5th of 2022, so over a year old and a lot of changes have happened under the hood since then. 100% agree the OP is using outdated or unsupported versions so they should all be updated. OP do updates, give it a try and report back your findings.